# convert custom date string to date object

Tags: javascript

How can I convert a string representation of a date to a real javascript date object?

the date has the following format

```
E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy
```

e.g.

```
Sat Jun 30 00:00:00 CEST 2012
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
My working solution is based on the accepted answer. To get it work in IE8, you have to replace the month part (e.g. Jun) with the months number (e.g. 5 for June, because January is 0)

Comment: Parse, create a valid string and call the Date constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510580/convert-string-to-datetime

Comment: and how do i handle the 'Z'?

Comment: i think you would need to somehow get the timezone offset and set it manually

Comment: use a database (precompiled hashmap, to be exact) or rely on the constructor. One form allows for a timezone string, IIRC

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your date string can mostly be parsed as is but `CEST` isn't a valid time zone in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), so you'll have to manually replace it with `+0200`.

A simple solution thus might be :

```
var str = "Sat Jun 30 00:00:00 CEST 2012";
str = str.replace(/CEST/, '+0200');
var date = new Date(str);
```

If you want to support other time zones defined by their names, you'll have to find their possible values and the relevant offset. You can register them in a map :

```
var replacements = {
    "ACDT": "+1030",
    "CEST": "+0200",
    ... 
};
for (var key in replacements) str = str.replace(key, replacements[key]);
var date = new Date(str);
```

[This might be a good list of time zone abbreviation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)

Comment: Tested in Firefox? I remember firefox being quite strict in which dates it accepts. It does work in Chrome, though.

Comment: Tested in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Can you test in IE too, or should I?

Comment: There might be a problem with the locale, too. "Jun" is hardly an universal notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to convert string into datetime:

```
var sDate = "01/09/2013 01:10:59";
 var dateArray = sDate.split('/');
 var day = dateArray[1];

 // Attention! JavaScript consider months in the range 0 - 11
 var month = dateArray[0] - 1;
 var year = dateArray[2].split(' ')[0];
 var hour = (dateArray[2].split(' ')[1]).split(':')[0];
 var minute = (dateArray[2].split(' ')[1]).split(':')[1];
 var objDt = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);
 alert(objDt);
```