# creating a new date with CEST timezone

Tags: javascript, date

I wonder why the next line works:

```
new Date("06/19/2019 06:42 EDT") //Wed Jun 19 2019 13:42:00 GMT+0300
```

But this one does not:

```
new Date("06/19/2019 06:42 CEST") //Invalid date
```

Comment: The date constructor expects RFC 8601 strings.  Anything else is fair game whether it works.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15494369/8353201

Comment: @amy—you might have meant ISO 8601 or RFC 2822 (or RFC 3339), but the ECMAScript parseable formats aren't exactly either. Best to just refer to relevant parts of ECMA-262. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors for JavaScript `Date` objects can use any of these syntax options:

1) `new Date();`
2) `new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [,
milliseconds]]]]]);`
3) `new Date(value);`
4) `new Date(dateString);`

---

Your examples are using option #4, `datestring` -- regarding which, n.b.:

> "Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor ... is strongly discouraged due to
>   browser differences and inconsistencies."

---

If you must use the `dateString` option for your constructor, the string needs to be "specified in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method" (that is, either an IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamp or a string in a version of ISO8601).

**This formatting requirement is likely where your attempt is going sideways -- but** as mentioned above, results will vary by browser -- so **you might consider constructing a default Date object and using the setters provided** by the `Date` class to assign your desired values.

For example (if the timezone you want matches the timezone where your script is running):

---

```js
const date = new Date();

date.setFullYear(2019);
date.setMonth(0); // Note that the months array starts with zero for January
date.setDate(1);

date.setHours(0);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);

console.log(date.toLocaleString()); // Logs `1/1/2019, 12:00:00 AM`
```

Lots more information can be found on this [MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).