# convert string into datetime by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My string is like `3/29/2016 17:30`.How to convert it into datetime in javascript?
and I want to compare it with another date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Comment: You can visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510580/convert-string-to-datetime and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript

Also refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

```
var date= new Date("2016-03-29 17:30:00".replace(/-/g,"/"));
```

if date is dynamic then you have to break that using `substring` method and concat in above format.