# Angular 2 - Building dates in constructor - Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, date, typescript

I trying to create a new date object for an ngx-chart following [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/HOXr8K?p=preview), specifically this code:

```
  constructor() {
    this.data = this.multi.map(group => {
      group.series = group.series.map(dataItem => {
        dataItem.name = new Date(dataItem.name);
        return dataItem;
      });
      return group;
    });
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

I understand using new Date()as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510580/convert-string-to-datetime) but I keep getting this error: "Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'." Which I also understand (because this is typescript), I just don't get how I am supposed to handle these two together. In the other examples I've seen this doesn't seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of type inference. you don't tell TS what type 'name' is. it sees the double quotes and infers a string. You have to tell TS that this is an `any`.

You'll have to create an interface like this:

```
interface Multi{
  name:String
  series: Array<{value: number, name: any}> // <-- note here it's explicitly any
}
```

then you use it:

```
export var multi: Multi[] = [
  {
    "name": "Tunisia",
    "series": [
      {
        "value": 3309,
        "name": "2016-09-19T10:24:08.741Z"
      }
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "El Salvador",
    "series": [
      {
        "value": 5714,
        "name": "2016-09-19T10:24:08.741Z"
      },
      ....
    ]
  }
]
```

Alternatively, instead of that long syntax in plunker, you can do this differently where TS would not mind like so:

```
 this.data = multi.map(group => 
       <any>{ // <-- tells TS this is explicitly any
         "name": group.name,
         "series": group.series.map(s => <any>{"value":s.value, "name":new Date(s.name)})
       });
```