# new Date('2011-12-15 00:00:00') is showing up as NaN

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer-9

The code: `new Date('2011-12-15 00:00:00')` is showing as `NaN`.
How can I convert this date?
Any helps are appreciated.

My code is very straight forward. It works in Chrome but not in IE 9.

```
var dateText = new Date('2012-08-01 00:00:00'); 
alert(dateText.getDate().toString() + "/" + dateText.getMonth().toString() + "/" + dateText.getYear().toString());
```

Comment: it's a date object, not a number, so if you're trying to cast it to int, it'll be NaN. But can't give a good answer without seeing a bit more of your code and what you're trying to do with it. Show us how you're getting NaN.

Comment: In case it's related, there's a bug in Safari/iOS which prevents that format from working... http://stackoverflow.com/a/4310986/29

Comment: I works perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RvAyu/.  There must be something else wrong with your code that you are not showing us.

Comment: The above code does not work in IE, works in Chrome. I am sorry for not mention that here. I am using IE 9 and my organization's default browser is IE 8 or 9.

Comment: @Spudley My code is very straight forward. It works in Chrome but not in IE 9. `var dateText = new Date('2012-08-01 00:00:00');
            alert(dateText.getDate().toString() + "/" + dateText.getMonth().toString() + "/" + dateText.getYear().toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search in web, realized that the stupid IE does not understand this date format. I do not know about Safari and Firefox, but certainly this works in Chrome.

Either I will have to use some javascript libraries like DateJS for doing this or will have to do some custom coding as below which I will never recommend. Fortunately in my case, I am sure that I will be getting the dates in the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS format.

```
var dateText = '2011-12-15 00:00:00';
alert(dateText.substring(5, 7) + "/" + dateText.substring(8, 10) + "/" + dateText.substring(0, 4));
```

Answer (score 6):

Add "T" to the date format. e.g:

```
new Date('2011-12-15T00:00:00')
```

Comment: I could get it working in Chrome not in the IE 9. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution I tried
Download date.js from http://datejs.com/
Include in your file
then
 var date = Date.parse('1970-01-12 00:00:00');
 var formattedDate = date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');

It works like charm in Safari.

Comment: I had already mentioned about DateJS in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11854411/740756). It was just a waste to include one more js library for just this case. new Date('2011-12-15 00:00:00') does not work only in IE. My intranet is mostly accessed by IE users and Safari or FF was irrelevant for me.