# JavaScript sort an array of arrays by the day of the week

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following variable (`console.log(response)`):

```
"['2013-04-15', 26]", "['2013-04-16', 10]", "['2013-04-17', 51]", "['2013-04-18', 46]", "['2013-04-19', 32]", "['2013-04-20', 50]", "['2013-04-21', 26]", "['2013-04-22', 31]", "['2013-04-23', 48]", "['2013-04-24', 821]", "['2013-04-25', 917]", "['2013-04-26', 949]", "['2013-04-27', 405]", "['2013-04-28', 593]", "['2013-04-29', 925]", "['2013-04-30', 877]", "['2013-05-01', 277]", "['2013-05-02', 112]", "['2013-05-03', 115]", "['2013-05-04', 62]", "['2013-05-05', 74]", "['2013-05-06', 76]", "['2013-05-07', 51]", "['2013-05-08', 93]", "['2013-05-09', 231]", "['2013-05-10', 350]", "['2013-05-11', 258]", "['2013-05-12', 0]", "['2013-05-13', 61]"
```

which I transform in an array of arrays in the following manner:

```
var json = response.replace(/"/g,'');
json = "[" + json + "]";
json = json.replace(/'/g,'"');
var myData = JSON.parse(json);
```

and I receive (`console.log(myData)`):

```
myData = [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
```

which I need to keep in this format for further usage.
I want to know if is possible to sort the response by the day of the week? And also if is possible to store in a variable for example only the monday days, tuesday days in another one and so on? I have to use JQuery for this, is even a function that suits my needs?

Comment: The best function that suits your needs is [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: @VisioN it also works for my array of arrays?

Comment: @DanielacostinaVaduva if you send your own comparison function as a strategy object it will

Comment: @DanielacostinaVaduva It works for any JavaScript arrays. And it doesn't care about the contents of these arrays, i.e. what data is stored there.

Comment: @Mortalus Strategy object? This could be something like `.getDay()` method?

Comment: @DanielacostinaVaduva see my answer below.

Comment: Uh, you really should make that response valid JSON.

Comment: @Bergi I am sorry but I have to use it this way... I send the response back echoing in php a json encode...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use method **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** passing your custom sorter function as parameter (see below).
In order to get the day-of-week of the date corresponding to each array's 1st element (e.g. "2013-04-15"), you can use Date's **[`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)** function.

```
var sorter = function(a, b) {
    /* The '.replace("-", "/")' part is for compatibility with Safari
       See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari */
    var d1 = new Date(a[0].replace("-", "/")).getDay();
    var d2 = new Date(b[0].replace("-", "/")).getDay();
    return d1 - d2;
};
myData.sort(sorter);
```

**NOTE**:
**[`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)** returns an integer between 0 and 6 (inclusive), which correspond to days-of-week Sunday through Saturday (Sunday is 0, Monday is 1...).

If you want to classify them by day-of-week instead of sorting, you can use something like this:

```
function classifyByDayOfWeek(customArr) {
    var byDayOfWeek = [[], [], [], [], [], [], []];
    for (var i = 0; i < customArr.length; i++) {
        var day = new Date(customArr[i][0]).getDay();
        byDayOfWeek[day].push(customArr[i]);
    };
    return byDayOfWeek;
}
myData = classifyByDayOfWeek(myData);
```

See also this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Zdc3A/)**.

Comment: How can I use this to create separate arrays corresponding for each of the day of the week?

Comment: This will almost certainly give you some errors on Safari, i believe that the only valid date that safari takes into account on javascript is formatted as mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @expert-system I am sorry, I have issues with your answer, can you provide a jsfiddle example please?

Comment: Please, see my updated answer. I addressed the possible Safari incompatibility and added link to a short demo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sort` function as VisioN suggested and pass your own comparison strategy.
Something like this should work for you:

```
myData.sort(function(a,b)
{
  if ((a[0]>b[0]) && (a[1]>b[1])) return 1
  if ((a[0]==b[0]) && (a[1]==b[1])) return 0
  if ((a[0]<b[0]) && (a[1]<b[1])) return -1
});
```

more info about sort: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

whit regards to my "Strategy Object" comment, here is some more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: That code has all sorts of bugs in it (pun intended). What does it return if `a[0] > b[0]` and `a[1] <= b[1]`? What if `a[0] == b[0]` and `a[1] != b[1]`? Or `a[0] < b[0]` and `a[1] >= b[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to create a separate array for each day of the week, a sort is not necessary

```
 myData = ["['2013-04-15', 26]", "['2013-04-16', 10]", "['2013-04-17', 51]", "['2013-04-18', 46]", "['2013-04-19', 32]", "['2013-04-20', 50]", "['2013-04-21', 26]", "['2013-04-22', 31]", "['2013-04-23', 48]", "['2013-04-24', 821]", "['2013-04-25', 917]", "['2013-04-26', 949]", "['2013-04-27', 405]", "['2013-04-28', 593]", "['2013-04-29', 925]", "['2013-04-30', 877]", "['2013-05-01', 277]", "['2013-05-02', 112]", "['2013-05-03', 115]", "['2013-05-04', 62]", "['2013-05-05', 74]", "['2013-05-06', 76]", "['2013-05-07', 51]", "['2013-05-08', 93]", "['2013-05-09', 231]", "['2013-05-10', 350]", "['2013-05-11', 258]", "['2013-05-12', 0]", "['2013-05-13', 61]"];

myData = myData.map (function (v) { // convert to useable form
  v = v.match (/^\['(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})',\s*(\d+)\]$/);
  return [v[1], v[2]];    
});

myDays = myData.reduce (function (days, v) {
  days[(new Date (v[0])).getDay ()].push (v);
  return days;
}, [[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]); // array of 7 arrays, one per day of week.

JSON.stringify (myDays);
```

-->

```
"[[["2013-04-21","26"],["2013-04-28","593"],["2013-05-05","74"],["2013-05-12","0"]],
  [["2013-04-15","26"],["2013-04-22","31"],["2013-04-29","925"],["2013-05-06","76"],["2013-05-13","61"]],
  [["2013-04-16","10"],["2013-04-23","48"],["2013-04-30","877"],["2013-05-07","51"]],
  [["2013-04-17","51"],["2013-04-24","821"],["2013-05-01","277"],["2013-05-08","93"]],
  [["2013-04-18","46"],["2013-04-25","917"],["2013-05-02","112"],["2013-05-09","231"]],
  [["2013-04-19","32"],["2013-04-26","949"],["2013-05-03","115"],["2013-05-10","350"]],
  [["2013-04-20","50"],["2013-04-27","405"],["2013-05-04","62"],["2013-05-11","258"]]
]"
```

Comment: And if I want one array for each of the day how I need to proceed?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is that not the `myData` that produces `myDays`? Or can you have multiple data points in a single day.?

Comment: I would like something like `SundaysData = [["2013-04-21","26"],["2013-04-28","593"],["2013-05-05","74"],["2013-05-12","0"]]` `MondaysData = [["2013-04-15","26"],["2013-04-22","31"],["2013-04-29","925"],["2013-05-06","76"],["2013-05-13","61"]]` and so on. It is possible?

Comment: Is that not what my final output is? There are 7 lines each an array of entries. Each line corresponds to a day of the week, the first being Sunday. To map to your notation use `SundaysData = myDays[0]; Mondaysdata = mayDays[1];` etc.