# Why i can not set date iinput type date in ipad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ipad

I am trying to set date in input type date using angular.js

js:

```
$scope.fromDate=new Date("1995-12-12");
```

html:

```
<input class="{{direction}}" type="date" name="fromDate" ng-model="fromDate"   value="{{fromDate}}">
```

It works fine in desktop but doesn't work in ipad. Does somebody know why?

Comment: Remove `value="{{fromDate}}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Safari doesn't understand new Date("1995-12-12");
See: [Invalid date in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari)

also:

http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari for formats that do work