# Years-only display on xAxis with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis-labels

I have a graph which displays a line over many days, months and years. I'd like to have on the xAxis only every xth year displayed. In Safari, it displays it correctly; in Firefox (41.0), it displays 1970 all the way through. Here [is a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cpnzhveu/4/).

The data look like this:

```
    Date,Value
    1-Jan-1993,
    2-Jan-1993,
    3-Jan-1993,
    4-Jan-1993,
    5-Jan-1993,-4.30161566849
```

The xAxis definition like this:

```
    xAxis: 
    {
        tickWidth: 0,
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: 
        {
           format: '{value:%Y}'
        }
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of what Firefox spits out:

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: It's probably problem with parsing your dates into timestamps - could you show code responsible for that part? Very unlikely it's a problem with Highcharts config.

Comment: I feel its not problem with highcharts, its something about the date format not supported while parsing in safari. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari

Comment: So most likely , you have to manipulate your csv to replace "-" with "/" , or read it in a javascript variable and replcace using (new Date('2011-04-12'.replace(/-/g, "/")))

Comment: Thanks a lot! [Here is the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cpnzhveu/4/) which shows the data and the conversion. I tried to replace the "-" with "/", but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Still struggling with this. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox cannot parse your date strings in their current format they all return the default datetime of 1 Jan 1970, replacing all the `-` seperators with spaces allows Firefox, Chrome and IE to parse the dates correctly as seen here
http://fiddle.jshell.net/z2uosh1a/

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Is there any way to know these things? I mean, a page which displays which data formats should be coded/displayed in which way? Or just a trial-and-error thing?

Comment: [This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) lists some implementations of firefox's Date.parse() function however it does boil down to a little trial and error inside the browser console.