# Display "hours and minutes" works on all browsers except safari. JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, vue.js

I receive a date from an object in a loop in this format : 2018-08-06 20:45:00

And I want to display only "20:45" (always with two digits for minutes) in the Timezone of the client. I have created this method in the methods part of vue.js :

```
ihaveadate(dateFromLoop) {
  var d = new Date(dateFromLoop);
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
  var hour = d.getUTCHours();
  var minutes = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" : "") + d.getMinutes();
  return `${hour}:${minutes}`;
}
```

It seemed to work fine except that on safari I have NaN:NaN, is there a clean solution to this problem ?

After reading ur answers i made it works like that :

```js
var dateFromLoop = '2018-08-06 20:45:00';
var date = Date.parse(dateFromLoop.replace(" ", "T"));
const daty = new Intl.DateTimeFormat({
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric"
}).format(date);
console.log(daty);
```

Comment: The respective post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari

Comment: Related: [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in Safari, for me it returns "07/08/2018". The timestamp "2018-08-06 20:45:00" doesn't have an associated time zone, so the time should always be "20:45" regardless of the timezone of the host. But Safari's parser is buggy, "2018-08-06T20:45:00" will be treated as UTC, not local, so don't trust it. Your answer code doesn't compile, it has syntax errors and bugs.

Comment: as i receive only  2018-08-06 20:45:00 i did that : const loopy = dateFromLoop.replace(" ", "T") + ".000+02:00";
      var date = Date.parse(loopy);
      const daty = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
        hour: "numeric",
        minute: "numeric"
      }).format(date);
      return daty;

Answer (score 3):

yes, this will not work on safari, as for [ECMAScript 5 ISO-8601 format support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> Alternatively, the date/time string may be in ISO 8601 format. For
>   example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date and
>   time) can be passed and parsed.

you need to include `T` withing the date time in order to make it work on Safari:

```
new Date('2014-02-18T15:00:48');
```

you can try and do it like this:

```
new Date(dateFromLoop.replace(/\s/, 'T');
```

Comment: That still produces an erroneous result in Safari.

Comment: can it depends on the version of safari because i see 20:45 on my side ?

Comment: @yoyojs—yes (tested in v 13.2.1 which is the current release). '2014-02-18T15:00:48' should be parsed as local so should return the same local date and time (i.e. 18 Feb 2014 15:00:48 regardless of local timezone), but Safari treats it as UTC, hence the different time for anyone with an offset other than +0.

Answer (score 1):

For a clean solution 
There is a library called moment by using that you can do all your time and date manipulation

for your problem in Moment

```
const d = new Date(yourDate);
const hourAndMin = moment().format('h:mm');
```

Refer [Moment](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vanilla for this.

[docs for parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

[docs for format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

The example direct from the source

```js
var date = Date.parse('2018-08-06 20:45:00'.replace(' ', 'T'));

// toLocaleString without arguments depends on the implementation,
// the default locale, and the default time zone
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat({
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric'
}).format(date));
```

Comment: This work well  but i have a shift of two hours in safari. I read in the doc that i can i find the user timezone like that  var tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone; but i don't know how to pass it in my DateTimeFormat

Comment: I can't understand why this is the accepted answer. The result In Safari 11 is "07/08/2018", the OP wants "20:45". Safari's parser is buggy, "2018-08-06T20:45:00" is incorrectly parsed as UTC so it will get the wrong time when using local methods and wrong date depending on the host timezone offset.

Comment: because, the op dimmed it the accepted answer and that's about it. It served his needs, so why must you question one's opinion and decisions? you are not the op of the question.

Comment: @BarrJ—it doesn't serve the OP's needs at all. It produces the wrong result and is parsed differently in Safari to other browsers (it would show the wrong time if it did display the time and for me it shows the wrong date as well). If the OP hasn't realised those errors, it would be remiss not to point them out.

Comment: but on safari i see "20:45" not "07/08/2018", am i missing something there ?