# new Date() returns wrong date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetime-format

I know this is a very basic question, but I am stuck on this for several hours. Why do I get the wrong date and time, when I pass my ISO String to `new Date()`

```
new Date('2017-08-01T00:00:00');
=> 2017-07-31T22:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: This look like a timezone issue

Comment: Where's your time zone specification?

Comment: I get the value from an API which provides the ISO String without time zone specification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: You should not use date time strings without time zones because not all current browsers handle those correctly.

Comment: 2017-08-01T00:00:00 is parsed as local (in compliant browsers) so represents a different moment in time in each system with a different offset. 2017-07-31T22:00:00.000Z is UTC, so your system timezone is likely UTC+0200.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Date('2017-08-01T00:00:00').toISOString() => 2017-07-31T18:30:00.000Z  (my timezone is +530)
new Date('2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z').toISOString() => 2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z (input is in UTC)
new Date('2017-08-01T00:00:00.000+0530').toISOString() => 2017-07-31T18:30:00.000Z
new Date('2017-08-01T00:00:00.000+0200').toISOString() => 2017-07-31T22:00:00.000Z
```

in your case, input date is not UTC and your system timezone is +0200 so you see the time difference. Second example shows there is no change in case of UTC.

Hope above examples clarify it.

Answer (score -1):

The returned date is an ISO 8601 date. 
This is the good date :)

```js
const test = new Date('2017-08-01T00:00:00');
const isoString = test.toISOString()
const dateString = test.toDateString()

console.log('iso', isoString)
console.log('date', dateString)
```

Comment: The OP knows it's an ISO 8601 format string, the question is why is the result not what the OP expects.