# Pass date variable to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying the find the difference in number of days between two dates.
One of the date is the current date and another is the date from the php variable passed to the view page. When i try to display the date it shows invalid Date.

Below is code:

```
 function checkcurrent()
    {

      var last_date= new Date( {!! json_encode($medic->end_day) !!});
      var new_last_date = new Date(last_date.getFullYear(),last_date.getMonth(),last_date.getDate());

      var diff = parseInt((new_last_date - today) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      window.alert(last_date);
    }
```

When i display just the `{!! json_encode($medic->end_day) !!}` it shows the date in the alert window. But when i pass it to the Date() it is not converted.
When last_date is displayed in alert box it shows invalid date. Why is it?
BTW the date im passing is of the format "23/08/2018" i.e "d/m/Y".
Someone please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: you need to inverse month and day

Comment: @jonatjano That is not a standard date format. Some implementations might support it, others might not.

Comment: @jonatjano that is not an optimal solution.

Comment: as @str said this is no standard format, the standard format for date is `YYYY-MM-DD` as defined by the [ECMAScript standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

Comment: @DevenderGupta the optimal solution would be timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function checkcurrent()
{
  var today = new Date();
  var last_date= new Date('{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $medic->end_day)->toDateString() }}');
  var new_last_date = new Date(last_date.getFullYear(),last_date.getMonth(),last_date.getDate());

  var diff = parseInt((new_last_date - today) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  window.alert(last_date);
}
```

I converted your date `$medic->end_day` to format `Y-m-d`. I've tested it and it works for me.

Comment: I've edited my answer about 1 minute ago. In the previous answer, I assumed that $medic->end_day is a Carbon date :D

Comment: Hey @Sang... What if after checking the diff i found that diff>0... then i want to make the $medic->current to 0. Its a boolean value. How to do this?

Comment: You can add to bellow your code `@php $medic->current = 0; @endphp`

Comment: inside the function itself?

Comment: I think you can add it into the place which you check diff > 0. It's not related with your origin question show I don't want to edit my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178601/discussion-between-devender-gupta-and-sang-nguyen).