# How to convert this date string to milliseconds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, milliseconds

I can get a date string from background, the format is `'Tue Sep 18 14:42:56 SGT 2018'`. I want to convert it to milliseconds in JavaScript.

I've already tried `Date.parse('Tue Sep 18 14:42:56 SGT 2018')`, but it will return `NaN`

Anybody can help? Appreciated in advance.

Comment: Related: [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+date+parse+string

Comment: new Date().getTime()

Comment: its a invalid date

Comment: hi... there is no day in your date string. Is that intended ?

Comment: But it works fine `Date.parse('Tue Sep 18 14:42:56 2018 GMT+0800')` or `Date.parse('Tue Sep 18 14:42:56 2018')`

Comment: @SarahRiddell Well, you changed the date string. And even with the change, it is still not a date format as per the specification and thus might not work in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

this is a valid date string that javascript cannot recognize ,tell the backoffice guys change the date format, better way is directly giving you the milliseconds.

Comment: ok. I will ask the backend engineer to pass me the milliseconds. Thanks.

Comment: That isn't an answer, it might be OK as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a bit of formatting to that string before you parse it. 
If you split it, you can build a valid format.

```
var dateString = 'Tue Sep 18 14:42:56 SGT 2018';
var pieces = dateString.split(" ");
var date = new Date(pieces[2]+" "+pieces[1]+" "+pieces[5]+" "+pieces[3]);
date.setHours(date.getHours()-8); // SGT to UTC
console.log(date.toString());
```

I created a jsbin for you. https://jsbin.com/jugonur/edit?html,js,console,output

See the valid formats here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: The date format you're creating is not a standard format (i.e. one supported by ECMA-262) and you've removed the timezone component. It makes no sense to parse the string to get the date parts, then create another string that must then be parsed again to crate a Date. Just pass the parts directly to the Date constructor. But you still need to resolve the offset. Fortunately, SGT is observed all year round, so -0800 will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @RobG I added a -8 to the hours. If I understand correctly, using the Date constructor creates a UTC date?