# How to get the year in date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a string like this : DD/MM/YYYY and i would like to get the year: YYYY the month: MM and the day: DD.

How can I do this by using javascript or typescript?

I already try to use the javascript function **getFullYear()** but I can't use this function in the string value. I have to convert the string to date. But I can't find the function.

```js
function converteDate() {
  let date1 = new Date('24/09/2018');
  console.log('Date ---', date1.getFullYear());
}
converteDate();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: that's an invalid date format

Comment: how can i convert it to a rigth format

Comment: Please see [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: `'24/09/2018'.split('/')[2]`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this work for your exact needs, but you may try this,

```
var parts ='24/09/2018'.split('/')
var d = new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
var n = d.getFullYear();
```

`n` holds year.

Comment: Only parts[2] is enough if only year is needed

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the input format is always DD/MM/YYYY, you can use this:

```
// for example: input = '24/09/2018'
var [d, m, y] = input.split('/').map(part => parseInt(part, 10));

console.log(y); // will log an 2018 as a number
```

This uses a so called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which requires ES6 support (or TypeScript).

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts ='24/09/2018'.split('/')
console.log("Parts :" , parts[2]);
```

Just store `parts[2]` in any variable.

```
var year = parts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will easily can be solve by using `split` function in Javascript...`split` function is used to split the given string into array of strings by separating it into sub strings using a specified separator provided in the argument.After spiting your string, you will have the year in the last index of the returned array.

```
function convertDate(date){
  let formatted = date.split('/');
  return formatted[formatted.length-1];
}
console.log(convertDate('24/09/2018'));
```