# Convert java date into angular date

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I am working on project uses angular4(frontend) and java(backend).
I get the date in below format from java backend server into angular server.

```
2018-05-23T18:30:00.000+0000
```

I need to convert it into javascript/angular Date object.
I have tried below code

```
Date d = new Date(java_date);
```

but this gives **Invalid Date** error.

Any idea how to deal with above date format.

Comment: That string is definitely a valid date, so the variable `java_date` must have some other string (or something else) in it.

Comment: Make sure you passing the date as `"2018-05-23T18:30:00.000+0000"` ,i.e., as string

Comment: Also it should be `let d = new Date(str)` not `Date d`.

Comment: That Java backend should be changed to return the result of `Instant.now().toString()` to get a standard `Z` on the end rather than `+0000`.

Comment: Related: [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

The string "2018-05-23T18:30:00.000+0000" is not consistent with the format in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date-time-string-format), it's missing colon in the timezone offset between the hours and minutes, so implementations may treat it as invalid (e.g. Safari).

You have a number of options:

1. Replace the timezone offset with "Z" and use the built–in parser: `new Date('2018-05-23T18:30:00.000Z')`
2. Insert a colon in the offset and use the built–in parser: `new Date('2018-05-23T18:30:00.000+00:00')`
3. Write your own parser for this particular format (maybe 4 lines of code)
4. Use a library (there are many good ones and they can help with formatting too)

I'd recommend either 3 or 4 as the built–in parser is notoriously fickle, but any of the above will likely do.

Answer (score 0):

The Date as you wrote it - given by its ISO string, you should parse it using JS/Angular

```
var a = Date.parse("2018-05-23T18:30:00.000+0000");
```

Here's a relevant link to MDN :

[MDN Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

[MDN ISO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: I face issue due to last +0000 
if I removed it then everything works perfect, but I don't  want to parse it using string manipulation.

Comment: Date constructor (when passed a string) calls Date.parse. You answer does not solve anything.

Comment: @PrasadParab What browser are you using? Seems to work fine in Chrome

Comment: @user184994

correct it works in Chrome but I have tried it on Safari12.0 there its not working

Comment: In that case, sounds like you have no choice but to manipulate the string value (maybe something like `java_date.substring(0, 23)`)

Comment: The string is not consistent with ECMA-262, do not recommend parsing it with the built–in parser as parsing is implementation dependent.

Comment: @user184994—you should manually parse the string. Either modify the string to be consistent with ECMA-262 (e.g. replace "+0000" with "Z" or "+00:00") or parse it with a custom function or library.