# getTime() not working on Safari the way it works on Chrome

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to get this to work on both Chrome and Safari? Works fine on Chrome. Returns NaN on Safari.

```
new Date("2018-11-22 14:24:34 -0800").getTime()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't pass the date as a `String` to the `constructor` of `Date` because that causes `Date.parse()` to be called.

> The `Date.parse()` method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC` or `NaN` if the string is unrecognized or, in some cases, contains illegal date values (e.g. 2015-02-31).
>
> **It is not recommended to use Date.parse** as until ES5, parsing of strings was **entirely implementation dependent**. *There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many different formats are to be accommodated).*
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

To mitigate those differences in implementation, I recommend you use a library like [*moment.js*](https://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for the safari browser support:

```
new Date(("2018-11-22 14:24:34").replace(/-/g, "/")).getTime().valueOf()
```