# momentjs format returns 0000-00-00

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to format a string date to `yyyy-mm-dd`. Typically, it comes as `d/m/yyyy` but regardless of the input, I want to have it as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```js
const date = new Date("13/10/2016");
const DateParsed = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

const dateParsed2 = moment("13/10/2016").format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I was expecting `2016-10-13` but I'm getting `0000-00-00` instead.

Comment: Not moment’s fault. Execute `new Date("13/10/2016")` on the console, and see what that says.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript

Comment: Which moment version are you using? With moment `v2.22.2` in Chrome on Win 10 I get `Invalid date`. As stated in the linked question `"13/10/2016"` is not a valid input for `Date.parse`, you can use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead.

Comment: @VincenzoC thank you! It worked. You can answer it so I mark it as an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input is not in a format recognized by `Date.parse`, I suggest to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead of `new Date()`.

Here a live sample:

```js
const date = "13/10/2016";
const DateParsed = moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(DateParsed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```