# How to sort array of object based on key that is date using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, object

I have an array as follow (date in `mm-dd-yyyy` format) in javascript.

```
[ 
  {'12-11-2018': 'NA' },
  { '12-05-2018': 'NA' },
  { '12-09-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-07-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-10-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-08-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-06-2018': 'pass' } 
]
```

I want to sort it using the date in ascending order.

**Expected output**

```
[ 
  { '12-05-2018': 'NA' },
  { '12-06-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-07-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-08-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-09-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-10-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-11-2018': 'NA' } 
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe there is an error in your expected output, `'12-06-2018'` is `'pass'` in the input, but `'NA'` in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sorting array. So use it and in function get key of object (date) using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and convert it to date object and then compare it.

```
var res = arr.sort((a,b) => new Date(Object.keys(a)[0]) - new Date(Object.keys(b)[0]));
```

```js
var arr = [
  {'12-11-2018': 'NA' },
  { '12-05-2018': 'NA' },
  { '12-09-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-07-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-10-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-08-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-06-2018': 'pass' } 
];
var res = arr.sort((a,b) => new Date(Object.keys(a)[0]) - new Date(Object.keys(b)[0]));
console.log(res);
```

---

**Update:**

The dates format isn't [javascript valid date format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715259/5104748), so maybe the code doesn't work in some browser. You can convert dates to javascript valid format to preventing this behavior.

```
let validDate = obj => {
  let arr = Object.keys(obj)[0].split('-');
  return new Date([arr[2], arr[0], arr[1]].join('-'));
};
let res = arr.sort((a,b) => validDate(a) - validDate(b));
```

```js
let arr = [
  {'12-11-2018': 'NA' },
  { '12-05-2018': 'NA' },
  { '12-09-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-07-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-10-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-08-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-06-2018': 'pass' } 
];
let validDate = obj => {
  let arr = Object.keys(obj)[0].split('-');
  return new Date([arr[2], arr[0], arr[1]].join('-'));
};
let res = arr.sort((a,b) => validDate(a) - validDate(b));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: '12-08-2018' is not a format supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent and you can't be sure that the objects will be sorted as expected using the built-in parser.

Comment: Reversing the order doesn't help. The OP is in m-d-y order, reversing gives y-d-m which is less likely to be parsed as required.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first key of each object, convert it to a date, then run a sort by comparing these dates:

```js
const data = [{
    '12-11-2018': 'NA'
  },
  {
    '12-05-2018': 'NA'
  },
  {
    '12-09-2018': 'pass'
  },
  {
    '12-07-2018': 'pass'
  },
  {
    '12-10-2018': 'pass'
  },
  {
    '12-08-2018': 'pass'
  },
  {
    '12-06-2018': 'pass'
  }
]

const getDate = str => {
  const parts = str.split('-')
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2])
}

const getFirstKey = obj => Object.keys(obj)[0]

const fullConversion = dateStr => getDate(getFirstKey(dateStr))

const sorter = (a, b) => fullConversion(a) < fullConversion(b) ? -1 : 1

const result = data.sort(sorter)

console.dir(result)
```

Comment: Worth a vote 'cos you parsed the timestamps correctly. :-)

Comment: @RobG Ha thanks! I'm always quite wary when it comes to timestamps in js

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the dates are in MM-DD-YYYY format, you can sort them by reformatting as ISO 8601 and using *localeCompare* to sort as strings. That avoids the built-in Date parser and associated issues, e.g.

```js
var data = [ 
  {'12-11-2018': 'NA' },
  { '12-05-2018': 'NA' },
  { '12-09-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-07-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-10-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-08-2018': 'pass' },
  { '12-06-2018': 'pass' } 
];

let mix = d => d.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/,'$3$1$2');
let key = Object.keys;

data.sort((a, b) => mix(key(a)[0]).localeCompare(mix(key(b)[0])));
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/,/g,',\n '));
```