# Angular Invalid Date Error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angular6

I receive this value (2018-12-19T14:07:03.068+0000) from a service of BE, try to transform in date

```
new Date('2018-12-19T14:07:03.068+0000')
```

This works in Chrome, but IE outputs "Invalid Date"

Comment: Use a specialized library (like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com)) to handle dates.

Comment: Or fix source to return a proper ISO format string

Comment: Try to add date like below will work with IE. var dt=new Date(2018, 12, 19, 14,07, 03); Output: https://i.postimg.cc/YCS6gtFJ/94.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a date with [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) or [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) format.

Comment: this is fine, but I receive this value from a service of BE

Comment: You should not rely on RFC2822 as it is not a supported date time format according to the ECMAScript specification.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because it is not a [valid date time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript). The best option would be to fix it in the backend. If you can't do that, fix it in the frontend. For example as follows:

```js
var invalidDate = '2018-12-19T14:07:03.068+0000';
var validDate = invalidDate.substring(0, 26) + ':' + invalidDate.substring(26);
console.log(validDate, new Date(validDate));
```