# How does one sort an array of same objects by a sub property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, properties

I have an array of items as follows:

```
myarray = [
    {
      somedate: "2018-01-11T00:00:00",
      name: "John Doe",
      level: 6000
    },
    {
      somedate: "2017-12-18T00:00:00",
      name: "Don Jhoe",
      level: 53
    },
    {
      somedate: "2016-12-18T00:00:00",
      name: "Jane Doe",
      level: 100
    },
    {
      somedate: "2018-10-18T00:00:00",
      name: "Dane Joe",
      level: 1
    }
]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to sort this array so that it is sorted by date.  I know how to sort an array of simple properties:

[Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
      // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
      // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
      return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
    });
```

But how is it best handled to sort an array by its items properties?

EDIT: Yes, those really are improper date strings provided by a strange web service that doesn't handle time.

Comment: Its `somedate` not `date`

Comment: Your example will work if you just change `a.date` to `a.somedate` and do the same for `b`

Comment: What do you mean by sub items?

Comment: "*improper date strings*" - They might be lacking milliseconds and a timezone, but they are [valid date time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript/). As long as those date strings either all or none contain a timezone, it should work (otherwise you might run into problems with Safari).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've posted actually works just fine.
All you need to do is compare `somedate` instead of `date`, and assign the final sort result to the original (if that is what is desired).

```
myarray = myarray.sort(function(a,b){
      return new Date(b.somedate) - new Date(a.somedate);
    });
```

Comment: Can't see the forest for the trees.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By having an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant date, you could use a string comparer, because the organization of the values (year, month, day, hour, etc) is descending and have the same length for every unit.

```js
var array = [{ somedate: "2018-01-11T00:00:00", name: "John Doe", level: 6000 }, { somedate: "2017-12-18T00:00:00", name: "Don Jhoe", level: 53 }, { somedate: "2016-12-18T00:00:00", name: "Jane Doe", level: 100 }, { somedate: "2018-10-18T00:00:00", name: "Dane Joe", level: 1 }];

array.sort(({ somedate: a }, { somedate: b }) => b.localeCompare(a)); // desc

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```