# Firefox 64 breaks some date parsing

Tags: javascript, date, firefox

Firefox appears to change how it parses a common if non-ISO date format in Javascript.

Until version 62, it failed to parse this date format:

```
(new Date("02-Nov-2018")).toISOString() //==> "Invalid Date"
```

That was great because you could detect that and fall back to use custom date format with a library like [moment](https://momentjs.org)

But now as of version 64 it "successfully" parses it as 2018 BCE, the end of the Agean bronze age:

```
(new Date("02-Nov-2018")).toISOString() //==> "-002018-11-02T04:56:02.000Z"
```

Stranger yet `.toISOString()` and `.toLocaleString()` return different date strings, and arguably at least one is incorrect:

```
(new Date("02-Nov-2018")).toLocaleString() //==> "11/2/2019, 12:00:00 AM"
```

By contrast, Chrome, Safari and IE parse it correctly.

Is there a way to get the old behavior back?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Btw 63 throwed "Invalid date" aswell.

Comment: Parsing of strings other than those supported by ECMA-262 is implementation dependent, which includes between versions of browsers. Don't use the built–in parser and it won't surprise you.

Comment: See [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)