# Filter an array of objects by date that > than date.now

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object, ecmascript-6

I'm having some problems with arrow functions and filtering array of objects by value of date.

I've tried to filter it but it returns full array, and did'nt working as it must be.

in the end i've got to return items - objects in array which expiration date is bigger than today. It must be arrow function

```
const menuItems = [{
    name: 'Hamburger',
    expirationDate: '09-24-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chicken',
    expirationDate: '10-03-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Hot-Dog',
    expirationDate: '03-24-2019'
  },
];

let today = new Date();
let dd = today.getDate();
let mm = today.getMonth();
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd;
}

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm;
}
today = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy;

console.log(today);

const filterByExpiration = (items) => {
  menuItems.filter(function() {
    return items.expirationDate > today;
  })
};
```

Comment: You're comparing strings and expecting the JS engine to understand that you want them to be viewed as date objects. Consider using a library for these types of comparisons: https://date-fns.org/v1.9.0/docs/isAfter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use Date.parse(date) to get the timestamp of the passed data and filter them if the difference with the current date is negative.
Your code should be something like this:

```
const menuItems = [
  {
    name: 'Hamburger',
    expirationDate: '09-24-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chicken',
    expirationDate: '10-03-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Hot-Dog',
    expirationDate: '03-24-2019'
  },
];

function filterByExpiration (items) {
  let today = new Date();
  let dd = today.getDate();
  let mm = today.getMonth();
  let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
  }
  today = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy;
  return menuItems.filter((item) => item.expirationDate > today)
};
```

Comment: This does not work in some browsers. See [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)?

Comment: Updated, now should be fine

Comment: That compares string lexicographically, not as dates, and the format used doesn't compare correctly as strings, e.g. `'06-20-2019' > '07-01-2018'` returns false, but should be true if compared as dates. Conversion to YYYY-MM-DD would work though.

Answer (score 0):

That's doing lexicographical comparison - not what you want. Just compare the two `Date`s together - and using an arrow function means you can also have an implicit return

```js
const menuItems = [{name:'Hamburger',expirationDate:'09-24-2019'},{name:'Pizza',expirationDate:'03-11-2019'},{name:'Sushi',expirationDate:'03-21-2019'},{name:'Chicken',expirationDate:'10-03-2019'},{name:'Steak',expirationDate:'05-27-2019'},{name:'Hot-Dog',expirationDate:'03-24-2019'}];
const today = new Date();
const filterByExpiration = arr => arr.filter(({ expirationDate }) => new Date(expirationDate.replace(/-/g, "/")) > today);
console.log(filterByExpiration(menuItems));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

The `replace` is to make the date strings into valid dates - not all browsers support hyphenated dates.

Comment: Destructuring is a nice touch, but not immediately obvious. Maybe you could add a footnote ?

Comment: No problem @msg, I'll add an ES5 variant.

Comment: Using the built–in date parser is not a good idea, especially for formats not supported by ECMA-262.

Answer (score -1):

```
const menuItems = [
  {
    name: 'Hamburger',
    expirationDate: '09-24-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pizza',
    expirationDate: '03-11-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sushi',
    expirationDate: '03-21-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chicken',
    expirationDate: '10-03-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Steak',
    expirationDate: '05-27-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Hot-Dog',
    expirationDate: '03-24-2019'
  },
];


const filterByExpiration = () => {
  const Today = Date.now()
  return menuItems.filter(function (item) {
    return new Date(item.expirationDate).getTime() > Today;
  });
};

filterByExpiration();
```

Read More About [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

### For Older Browsers

```
var filterByExpiration = () => {
  var Today = new Date(); 
  return menuItems.filter(function (item) {
    var year = Today.getFullYear();
    var month = Today.getMonth()+1;
    var day = Today.getDay();
    var dateYearArray = item.expirationDate.split('-');
    var dateYear = dateYearArray[2];
    var dateMonth = dateYearArray[0];
    var dateDay = dateYearArray[1];
    var isYear = year > dateYear;
    var isMonth = month > dateMonth;
    var isDay = day > dateDay;
    return !(isYear || isMonth || isDay);
  });
};


filterByExpiration();
```

Comment: This does not work in some browsers. See [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)?

Comment: @str what exactly does not work in the edited code?

Comment: `new Date('09-24-2019')` => `Invalid Date`

Comment: @str to I have to compare it month by `Date.getMonth()+1` and day by `Date.getDate()` and year by `Date.getFullYear()`

Comment: @str can you check the newly edited code? (does it work)?

Comment: The "for older browsers" function is seriously flawed (and the only reason for "older" is the use of *const*, which is unnecessary). Parsing strings with the built–in parser is not a good idea, particularly when the string is not a  format supported by ECMA-262.

Comment: @RobG what about `var`s?

Comment: @JamalAbo—fine, but it doesn't fix the logic errors, e.g. just because the month number is higher doesn't mean the date is later. E.g. 2019-01-01 has a lower month number than 2018-12-02, but is later. The same for the day number.

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing two different string. Its much better to convert both date object in timestamp or any value where you can compare.

```
new Date(); //gives something like this Wed Jun 26 2019 02:55:59 GMT+0530
```

and you are trying to compare with '03-24-2019' something like this. Possible flow would be :

```
const menuItems = [{
    name: 'Hamburger',
    expirationDate: '09-24-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chicken',
    expirationDate: '10-03-2019'
  },
  {
    name: 'Hot-Dog',
    expirationDate: '03-24-2019'
  },
];
const today = new Date().getTime();
const filterByExpiration = menuItems.filter((items)  => {
    return new Date(items.expirationDate).getTime() > today;
  })
console.log(filterByExpiration)
```

Comment: This does not work in some browsers. See [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)? And there are already three similarly non-working answers.