# Why JavaScript parses data wrongly?

Tags: javascript

There are two strange things:

- day 30 instead of 31?
- it set 13 as time instead of 00?

  ```
  new Date('Dec 31, 2019').toISOString()
  // '2019-12-30T13:00:00.000Z'
  ```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to convert original data format into `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: It seems you are in a +11 time zone and this shows you the UTC time, so it's correct, it just doesn't have the time offset.

Comment: You forgot to take the timezone into account.

Answer (score 1):

`new Date('Dec 31, 2019')` - this date will be shown in your local time format.

e.g.:

```
`Tue Dec 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1100` (Your Standard Time)
```

However, `new Date('Dec 31, 2019').toISOString()` - this date will be shown like

`2019-12-30T13:00:00.000Z`. It means Dec 31, 2019 minus 11 hours(your time zone).

In addition, to avoid strange behaviors, try to set explicitly year, month and day to avoid strange behavior.

You should parse `Date` in the following format:

```
// yyyy-mm-dd format
// new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
let yourDate = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // Be careful: months are 0-based
```

[You can see valid Date times here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript/)

Comment: This will still create a date in the local time zone which will be "incorrect" the same way when converted to UTC

Comment: @downvoter what's reason to downvote?