# Javascript date conversion and adding days

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date in the form of a string like below:

var dateInput= "Sat Dec 7 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)";

I want to convert this date to `dd/mm/yyyy` and be able to add and subtract days from this date and still retain the same format.

Here's what I did to convert this string to `dd/mm/yyyy` date format: 
I used this helper function:

```
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat);
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```

So, then I did :

```
var date = new Date(convertDate(eddFromCouch));
```

which gave me the string `7/12/2019`;

Then, when I tried to add the 5 days to the date above, I got the following:

```
date = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5);
console.log(date);   // returns 1563310800000
```

I believe `1563310800000` a UNIX timestamp which converts to `July,16,2019`

I was expecting it to return `12/12/2019`.

Comment: Use momentJS its very easy to do things like this

Comment: @Kevin.a adding dependencies for small requirements is not the best thing to do though

Comment: @AyushGupta I know that. Just suggesting it incase he might need to repeat similar actions in the future :)

Comment: And as `new Date()` behave differently in some browsers, using momentJs is always a best practice for me.

Comment: `new Date()` does not "behave differently in some browsers" if you use it according to the specification (with very few exceptions). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can achieve this using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). This library makes tasks like parsing, manipulating and displaying dates much easier to achieve.

```js
var input = "2019-08-14T08:06:49.288Z";
var date = moment(input);
date.add(5, "days");

console.log(date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would like to achieve this with js only.

Comment: Okay I appreciate that, this demonstrates another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dateInput` is actually the format returned by [date.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString), and can be passed directly to the date constructor to get a date object.

```js
function toDDMMYYY(date) {
  let parts = [];
  let dd = date.getDate();
  let mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    parts.push(`0${dd}`)
  } else {
    parts.push(`${dd}`)
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    parts.push(`0${mm}`)
  } else {
    parts.push(`${mm}`)
  }
  parts.push(yyyy)
  return parts.join('/');
}

const input = "Sat Dec 7 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)";
let date = new Date(input);
date = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5));
console.log(toDDMMYYY(date))
```

Comment: @Ayush, I would like to display it in dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: @PrerakSola added