# How to resolve "TypeError: is not a function" error in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to transform a date with the `.toLocaleDateString()` but I can't figure out what is wrong with the code below. I have tried to pass `todo.dueAt` to a method defined under the `<script>` tag which would return with the transformed date, but I got the same `TypeError: todo.dueAt.toLocaleDateString is not a function"`issue.

Why it should be a function at all and why is it work only with the `todo.dueAt`?

```
<template>
    <div class="todo-table">
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Done</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th>Due Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
            <td> {{ todo.isCompleted}}</td>
            <td> {{ todo.title }}</td>
            <td> {{ todo.dueAt.toLocaleDateString("hu-HU") }}</td>
            <td> {{ todo.dueAt.toLocaleDateString("hu-HU") }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoList",
  props: {
    todos: Array
  },
  method: {
    formatDate: (date) => {
      return date.getFullYear() + "." + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "." + date.getDate();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `todo.dueAt` is not a `Date`

Comment: `todo.dueAt` is really of type `Date`? It could be of type `string`, and that's a reason for this error

Comment: Please show us an example of what is in your `todos` array. Are you sure that `todo.dueAt` exists and is a Javascript `Date` object? Does your browser support `toLocaleDateString` yet? You can check that by executing `console.log((new Date()).toLocaleDateString)` in your dev console and making sure that it returns a function and not `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you All! You were right, todo.dueAt was converted to a string during fetch and that caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
The answer assumes the value todo.dueAt is a valid timestamp and can be converted to a Date object directly. Please do not use this if the format of dueAt is not known

One way is to wrap the todo.dueAt with a `new Date()`
The constructor can wrap even if the parameter is a Date type, so it will ensure that the time is a valid Date object

```
 <tr v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
            <td> {{ todo.isCompleted}}</td>
            <td> {{ todo.title }}</td>
            <td> {{ todo.dueAt && new Date(todo.dueAt).toLocaleDateString("hu-HU") }}</td>
            <td> {{ todo.dueAt && new Date(todo.dueAt).toLocaleDateString("hu-HU") }}</td>
          </tr>
```

Even if the dueAt is already a Date, wrapping it will not create a problem

```js
console.log(new Date(new Date()));
```

A better solution is to check if the value is an instance of Date() before the operation

```
(todo.dueAt instanceof Date) ? /*use LocaleDateString*/ : /* Convert and use */
```

Comment: Instead of adding a workaround TO should fix the source of the problem.

Comment: the source is that the dueAt is not a valid Date object, so the solution is wrapping it as a Date(). it could be a string from the server as a JSON. This is as much a solution as a work around, it has to be converted to a date object at some point. It is okay to do it before explicit use of a Date function. You could also write a check to see if todo.dueAt is an instance of Date and wrap it to a new Date() if not; I can add it to the answer

Comment: Also you are just guessing that their current `todo.dueAt` contains something that is convertible to a date. It could be a string in any arbitrary format or a unix timestamp (and in that case you wouldn't know whether in seconds or miliseconds)...

Comment: Thank you @DhananjaiPai! Yes, the problem was that the todo.dueAt was Date in the back-end but after JSON fetch, it converted to a String, but this solution converted it back without problem.

Comment: That's because [JSON does not have date type](http://json.org/). You should ensure that your backend creates a date string which is a [valid date time string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript).

Comment: Probably better to convert to Date in the subscription, rather than in the template. Store the value as a Date in memory, rather than as a string.

Comment: Thanks, @Rich! Could you please link some documentation to that, I am not quite sure how to do that or what to look for?

Comment: I wasn't referring to a specific function. I just meant that when you fetch the data, you should preemptively cast it as a Date, rather than doing nothing with it and keeping it as a String. I'm not familiar with Vue, so I can't tell you how to specifically do it, but it should just be a matter of using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your array, casting the date string as a date, and storing the resultant array. The goal is to have the template only be responsible for displaying data, and not also for manipulating it