# From date to date validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datetime

I want to validate from and to date. my date format is d/m/Y H:i

Here is my code:

```
    var startDate = new Date($('#fromdate').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#todate').val());
    if (endDate.getTime() <= startDate.getTime()) {
        return [false,"To Date cannot be less than From Date"];
    }else{
        return [true,""];
    }
```

result showing 'Invalid Date'.

Here the date format is different. How to change the date format before passing to Date function?.

Comment: next time please add example input.

Comment: However, you can parse the given date using [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: See [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the date string on your own or you can use an external library, like [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) or [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

A simple parsing function could be something like this (assuming the format is the one you mentioned in your question):

```js
function getDateFromCustomFormat(dateString) {
  const dateFormatPattern = /^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})$/

  const parts = dateString.match(dateFormatPattern)
  console.log(parts)

  const validFormatString = `${parts[3]}-${parts[2]}-${parts[1]} ${parts[4]}:${parts[5]}`
  new Date(validFormatString)
}
```

Comment: I believe OP knows that the format is incorrect and is asking **how** it can be changed

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava you're right, I'm gonna change my answer.

Comment: Parsing a string to create another string that is then parsed by the built–in parser is not a good strategy. From the initial parse, pass the values directly the Date constructor. Dates in the format y-m-d h:m are not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent and at least one current implementation will return an invalid date.