# How to format a String to Date in React Native?

Tags: javascript, date, react-native

I am getting a `Date` as a `String` in this format from the server `yyyyMMdd:hhmmss`.

Is there a generic way to format this string to a `Date` object?

**EDIT**

```
 formatDate = (data) => {
    return data.slice(6, 8) + "." + data.slice(4, 6) + "." + data.slice(0, 4) + " " + data.slice(9, 11) + ":" + data.slice(11, 13)
}
```

Comment: There are many libraries for these kinds of issues like momentjs. Have you tried !?

Comment: I try to stay away from packges for this simle things. I solved this issue with split function but I am not happy with that.

Comment: I believe that If you are not worried about daylight saving or timezones etc your solution is good enough.

Comment: I will keep my solution for now, maybe someone else has encountered and solved this issue. Thank you anyway

Comment: Maybe take a look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)?

Comment: The only "generic" way to date string parsing is to use a [valid date time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript) in the first place.

Comment: "*I solved this issue with split function but I am not happy with that*" Why not? Splitting into parts and passing to the Date constructor is the **only** way.

Comment: @RobG That would do it. Thanx

Comment: Cool. If you want to improve your code, post it with whatever you think the issues are and you might receive help with that. ;-)

Comment: Nice I will post my function for formatting the date

Comment: Ok, so what you're doing is just reformatting a string, the fact that it's a date is not important. The way you're doing it is fine, though there are alternatives, e.g. using *match* and *replace*.

Comment: _"I try to stay away from packages for this simple things"_ — Dates and Date/Time are _not_ simple things. They are, to the contrary, _very_ complicated to get right.

Comment: @StephenP Yeah i know it's complicated, but in my case I just want to display the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're reformatting the string is fine, even though it seems like a lot of code for a small job, *slice* is pretty fast. Some alternatives (not necessarily "better", just different):

```js
// Reformat yyyyMMdd:hhmmss as dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss
function formatMatch(s) {
  let b = s.match(/\d\d/g) || [];
  return `${b[3]}.${b[2]}.${b[0]}${b[1]} ${b[4]}:${b[5]}:${b[6]}`;
}

function formatReplace(s) {
  return s.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}):(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$3.$2.$1 $4:$5:$6');
}

formatDate = (data) => {
    return data.slice(6, 8) + "." + data.slice(4, 6) + "." + data.slice(0, 4) + " " + data.slice(9, 11) + ":" + data.slice(11, 13)
}

let s = '20200323:123445';
console.log(formatDate(s));
console.log(formatMatch(s));
console.log(formatReplace(s));
```

If you want to get an actual Date object, then instead of using the bits to create another string, just pass them into the constructor:

```js
// Parse yyyyMMdd:hhmmss to Date object
function parseD(s) {
  let b = s.match(/\d\d/g) || [];
  return new Date(b[0]+b[1], b[2]-1, b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6]);
}

let s = '20200327:134523';
console.log(parseD(s).toString());
```

The use of `|| []` means that if there's no match, an empty array is returned so all the `b[*]` terms return *undefined* and the result is an invalid date.

The above uses *match*, but *slice* or *substring* can be used the same way.

Comment: Well done Sir. I love the way you solve this problem. Thank you