# (XPages)How can I write the code for calculate the number of days between dates?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, hcl-notes

I have a field name, called `"REF_DATE"`. The `"REF_DATE"'s` format is `"YYYY/MM/DD"`.

I need to calculate the number of days from today to the `"REF_DATE"`.

For example:

`REF_DATE = 2020/01/09`

`Today = 2020/04/01`

The following is I tried the code:

```
var s1 = "2020/01/09";
var s2 = "2020/04/01";
var aDate = s1.split("/");
var oDate1 = Date.UTC(aDate[1],aDate[2],aDate[0]);
var bDate = s2.split("/");
var oDate2 = Date.UTC(bDate[1],bDate[2],bDate[0]);
var iDays = Math.floor((oDate2 - oDate1)/86400000);
return oDate1+"<br>"+oDate2+"<br>"+iDays+"<br>";
```

But the `xpages` showed `"853"`.

So, I need you guys to help me with how to calculate the number of days between dates.

Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: When I run the code above I get `83`

Comment: That code might yield different results because of daylight savings.

Comment: I tried that method "new Date(aDate[1], aDate[2], aDate[0]);".But the answer is "853".....

Comment: See this answer for a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289883/906113

Comment: If I used the "console.log()", the code can't work.....

Comment: "the code can't work" is not helpful. What happens? Do you get an error? It works for me. Depending on your browser, you might run into a problem because you are using [invalid date time formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript). But again: See the answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: I wrote this code in XPages of IBM Domino Designer. And in the web browser preview(Google). After I ran the code, the web browser is blank. So I don't know where is the problem of the code.

Comment: @str: "It works for me." is not helpful. You did not even ask which kind of JS engine Ariel is using...

Comment: Arguments are passed in the wrong order. Month should be offset by one to be between 0 and 11.

Comment: It says `(year, month, day)` here: https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/reference/r_wpdr_standard_date_utc_r.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the year as the first Date.UTC parameter and subtract 1 from the month (0 is January):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">    
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var s1 = "2020/01/09";
    var s2 = "2020/04/01";
    var aDate = s1.split("/");
    var oDate1 = Date.UTC(Number(aDate[0]), Number(aDate[1]-1), Number(aDate[2]));

    var aDate = s2.split("/");
    var oDate2 = Date.UTC(Number(aDate[0]), Number(aDate[1]-1), Number(aDate[2]));

    var iDays = Math.floor((oDate2 - oDate1) /1000/60/60/24);
    print(iDays);
}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the "console.log();" isn't work for my JS engine. And the result still showed "853"......

Comment: This works for you but not for me. What's your JS engine? My JS engine is "XPages".

Comment: Yes, it works in XPages.  I have modified the answer again with the full XPage.  Have you corrected your mistake in order of year, month, day?

Comment: I used your code on Apr 7. So the code didn't work for me. 
After you edited on Apr 9, I used your code on Apr 10.
Now, the code can work for me in XPages. 
I really appreciate your answer. Thanks!!!!!!!!