# Why do I get hours wrong from date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, date, datetime

I want to get the hours and minutes from a date string so I convert it to a date and then use the getHours() and getMinutes() methods. Problem is that the result is 12:20 instead of 10:20. **Why does this happen and how can I get the right hour?**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date("2020-05-28T10:20:00.000Z");
  hours = d.getHours();
  minutes = d.getMinutes();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Here you have a JSFiddle to try it:

https://jsfiddle.net/oqLsna0e/1/

Thank you!

Comment: Use: new Date('2020-05-28 10:20:00'), remove .000Z

Comment: @AksJacoves Do not do that. It relies on a non-specified date/time format and breaks in some browsers.

Comment: @str I did not know that. Thanks for the info

Comment: @AksJacoves You're welcome :) Maybe you would like to read [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript) to learn more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getHours` method is retrieving the hours according to where the app is hosted. In your case the app must be hosted in a CEST timezone (GMT+2).

You need to use the `getUTCHours` method to get the hours in UTC since that is how you are specifying the date using ZULU.

Answer (score 3):

The `z` at the end of the string means zero hour offset that is `UTC`. `Date.getHours` returns the hour according to your `local` time so it is not wrong. `Date.getUTCHours` returns the UTC+-0 hour.

If you need to work with timezones there are plenty of libraries such as [day.js](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).