# JavaScript Date object with timezone error on Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox

I need to create javascript object with timezone CST/CDT, below line of code is working fine in chrome but not on firefox

```
new Date("2020-06-06 05:37:34.0" + ' CST/CDT');
```

Chrome result:

```
Sat Jun 06 2020 15:37:34 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

Firefox result:

```
Invalid Date
```

need suggestions to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to use UTC dates, meaning storing and performing calculations on Dates as [UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

If you want to create a Date object specific to the timezone, do the below, I have shown how it can be converted back to UTC/local time zone:

```
const date = new Date('2010-05-11T10:11:00-0500');//CDT time
console.log(date.toString()); //date as per the current timezone of the machine this code is executed => "Tue May 11 2010 20:41:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
console.log(date.toISOString());//converts the Date as UTC based ISO date string => "2010-05-11T15:11:00.000Z"
```

Comment: but the result is different when creat date object with "CST/CDT"