# Javascript returns valid date of invalid date-string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, parsing

When I try to parse a string - to check if it is a valid date, javascript parses it as a date, and returns a valid date.

```js
console.log(new Date("Agent 007"));  // returns Sun Jul 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0200 
console.log(Date.parse("Agent 007")); // returns 993938400000
console.log(moment.utc("Agent 007").valueOf()); // returns 993945600000
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

How to prevent it ?

For you @Andreas:
Chrome Debugger console window:
[image]

Comment: which browser/node version are you using ?

Comment: In addition to the [standard date time string formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript), JavaScript implementations are allowed to parse whatever they want. You can't prevent that.

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)