# Convert date time string to UTC date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime

How can I convert `"2011-09-30T00:00:00"` date time string to UTC date in JavaScript?

I tried `new Date("2011-09-30T00:00:00")` but it converts to `"2011-09-29T23:00:00.000Z"`.

Comment: `new Date("2011-09-30T00:00:00")` should not convert it to `"2011-09-29T23:00:00.000Z"`, that happens only if you do `new Date("2011-09-30T00:00:00").toISOString()`. 
Where are you trying this? Have you tried `new Date("2011-09-30T00:00:00").toUTCString()`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried toUTCString but I need a date object while toUTCString returns a string. Would new Date( new Date("2011-09-30T00:00:00").toUTCString()) return a UTC date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```js
function createDateUTC(dateUTC) {
    return new Date(dateUTC + "Z");
}

var dateUTC = createDateUTC("2011-09-30T00:00:00");

console.log(dateUTC);
```

Comment: Interesting! - So does adding a "Z" makes it a UTC date?

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Comment: @developer—see [*What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript) and [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Sorry for the delay but @RobG already quoted some good topics about the reason why the code worked and why the issue happened.

Answer (score 1):

```
function createDateAsUTC(dateYmd) {
    var dateYmdSplited = dateYmd.split('-');
    var y = Number(dateYmdSplited[0]);
    var m = Number(dateYmdSplited[1]) - 1;
    var d = Number(dateYmdSplited[2])

    return new Date(Date.UTC(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0))
}

var fecha = "2021-09-01";
var d = createDateAsUTC(fecha);
```