# New Date() and New Date(string) not using the same timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

In JavaScript, why does those two lines of code use different time zone?

```
new Date("09/12/2021 15:00:03 UTC")
```

Returns Sun Sep 12 2021 11:00:03 GMT-0400 (**Eastern Daylight Time**)

```
new Date()
```

Returns Sun Sep 12 2021 10:00:03  GMT-0500 (**Eastern Standard Time**)

Why are they not both on  GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)???

The lines are one after the other in code, so they are run by the same server.

Thanks.

-- EDIT --

I tried with ISO format and the timezone is still wrong.

```
new Date("2021-09-12T16:34:14.000Z")
```

And the output is Sun Sep 12 2021 12:34:14 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: `"09/12/2021 15:00:03 UTC"` is not a standard format for the `Date` constructor. It leads to implementation-dependent behaviour.

Comment: @VLAZ What should the format be?

Comment: [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715259)