# How to make Date work in IE11 when using this type of string such as '2022-05-06 12:00:00'?

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer-11

I have found that new Date('2022-05-06 12:00:00') didn't work in IE11,only new Date('2022/05/06 12:00:00') works
However,I have writen a lot of codes like that,so how can I make the Date fit the IE11 by rewrite the Date Class?

Comment: Rewrite the date class?

Comment: *"I have found that new Date('2022-05-06 12:00:00') didn't work in IE11"* It also isn't necessarily reliable in any other browser, as that isn't in the only officially-specified format. One browser might parse it as UTC, another as local time; or as you've found, a browser may even not parse it at all. You'll need to parse it yourself if you want to handle it consisstently cross-browser .

Comment: Relevant: [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715259) It should be easier to fix your inputs instead of *rewriting the `Date` class*. It's one of those tasks that if you have to ask how to do, you most likely shouldn't do.

Comment: ok，I have solved it,by rewrite the date class to fix the ie11