# Why in javascript, new Date EPOCH is not in UTC EPOCH?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, epoch

I have trouble with time precision on my backend.
here is code sample:

```js
const inputDateString = `2022-05-30 13:45:15` // assume it as UTC without specifying the timezone

// we use loadbalancing and auto-scale so our backend engine might be everywhere,
// so we dont take local time into account, we always treat date as UTC
let systemGetDate = new Date(inputDateString)

console.log(systemGetDate.valueOf()) // => 1653893115000, it should be 1653918315000
// 1653893115000 is GMT: Monday, 30 May 2022 06:45:15, but 2022-05-30 13:45:15 in my local time!
const inputDateStringWithTimezone = `2022-05-30 13:45:15+00`
systemGetDate = new Date(inputDateStringWithTimezone)
console.log(systemGetDate.valueOf()) // => 1653918315000, its right now. but only when timezone explicitly specified
```

Can we make new Date(string) always treat the input as UTC, without converting it as localtime? I'm fine the `Date` object is in localtime, but atleast the `getTime` or `valueOf` in UTC somehow.

Currently my workaround is by using `moment.js` library, it can resulting the output what I want.

but I know it will be bad to depends too much on other library, it may break or deprecated later.
(https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status, the official itself explain it will be discontinued)

any better workaround to fix this issue? or I should scratch all this, and explicitly specify the timezone all around the system?

Comment: Dates *do* treat inputs as UTC already. The timestamp value of a date instance is always UTC. The confusion starts when you convert a date instance to a string.

Comment: "*Can we make `new Date(string)` always treat the input as UTC?*" - no. Or: only by always specifying the timezone in the input string.

Comment: @Bergi isn't the default "Z0"? I don't try that very often so I forget. *edit* I guess just "Z".

Comment: @Pointy [It's complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51715260/1048572) :-)

Comment: @Bergi—"timezones" aren't supported as such (by ECMA-262, implementations may though), but offsets are. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> const inputDateString = `2022-05-30 13:45:15` // assume it as UTC without specifying the timezone
> ```

Timestamps without a timezone or offset are treated as local, not UTC. The format of that particular timestamp is not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent (see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)) and may result in an invalid Date or unexpected value.

> Can we make new Date(string) always treat the input as UTC, without converting it as localtime?

Yes, by reformatting it to a supported format that the built–in parser should treat as UTC, e.g.:

```
'2022-05-30T13:45:15Z'
```

Alternatively you can parse it yourself and pass the values to *Date.UTC* so they're treated as UTC, e.g.

```js
let date = `2022-05-30 13:45:15`;

// Reformat and use the built–in parser
let reformattedDate = date.replace(' ','T') + 'Z';
console.log(new Date(reformattedDate).toISOString());

// Using Date.UTC
let [Y, M, D, H, m, s] = date.split(/\D/);
let d = new Date(Date.UTC(Y, M-1, D, H, m, s));

console.log(d.toISOString());
```