# Convert Textual date to Timestamp with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timestamp

I have this textual date: "4 September 2022" (literally a text label inserted manually)

How can I convert it in timestamp with jQuery?

Comment: This isn't really a jQuery question. It's a JavaScript question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `new Date()` & `getTime()`

Check this example.

```js
const timestamp = new Date("4 September 2022").getTime();

console.log(timestamp);
```

Comment: Note: this is not guaranteed to work across all browsers. See [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715259/215552)