# Why does JavaScript add a timestamp to my Date when pulling from Postgres DB?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-fns

I am having dates mismatching when pulled from my postgres db. In the database, the date is stored as a `Date` value represented as `2023-03-01`, but when I fetch it from the db to use in my JavaScript code, it comes through with a timestamp attached even though `Date` representations don't have a timestamp.

In my db the date is `2023-03-01`, but once imported via postgres in my middleware, it is stored as the string `2023-03-01T00:00:00.000Z`.

Now if I need to manipulate that date in my code, I need to create a new `Date` object and manipulate it as necessary (i'm using `date-fns`), but if I run `new Date()` on that value I get Feb 28 instead of Mar 1.

Why does the JavaScript `new Date()` method not return the same value when you use a `/` vs a `-` in the string passed in?

```js
new Date('2023-03-01')
Tue Feb 28 2023 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
new Date('2023/03/01')
Wed Mar 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

When you use a `-` to separate the year-month-day, the date is created for UTC time, which for me in CO, makes 3/1 turn into 2/28 or 3/1 Midnight(UTC).

If however you use a `/` to separate the year/month/day, the date is created for 3/1 Midnight(MST).

So I've had to create a method to remove the timestamp and then convert all the `-`'s to be `/` in order to get the correct date to manipulate.  I just feel like there has to be a better way.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: One of them is reading in UTC, the other is in your local timezone.

Comment: One of them is valid format according to the spec, the other not and thus implementation dependent. [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715259)

Comment: ECMAScript *Date* objects are just an offset from the epoch (1 Jan 1970 UTC), so they always represent a particular date and time. There is no date–only or time–only representation (the proposed [*Temporal* object](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) should fix that).