# How do I make a JavaScript countdown using a Unix timestamp?

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp, countdown

I am making a website that needs a countdown until a specific time, but I can't find anything that lets me input a Unix timestamp and gives the same countdown for all users, regardless of timezones.

I found some stuff using jQuery and other libraries, but I don't want to use any libraries unless I absolutely have to.

Here is what I tried:

```js
const countdownTimer = setInterval(() => {
    const countDownTime = new Date("Mar 1 2024 11:00:00").getTime();
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    const timeLeft = countDownTime - currentTime;

    const daysLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hoursLeft = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutesLeft = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const secondsLeft = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    if (timeLeft < 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementsByClassName("countdown")[0].innerHTML = "Released!";
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName(
            "countdown"
        )[0].innerText = `${daysLeft}d ${hoursLeft}h ${minutesLeft}m ${secondsLeft}s`;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Everything works as expected, except the time is in my current timezone which is not what I want, because this is a countdown until a website I'm making releases.

Comment: Well, all you really need to change is `new Date("Mar 1 2024 11:00:00")` to pass in a Unix timestamp. That should be it - timestamps are time zone agnostic. Your string there is interpreted as local time. Don't use randomly formatted strings, btw.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks! I will try that. What do you mean by randomly formatted strings?

Comment: The only standard format for datetime strings is ISO format, not human formats like `Mar 1 2024`

Comment: It's not a [valid format officially supported format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript). Anything that's not an officially supported format is just random. It'd be implementation dependent how or if it will be interpreted. You can expect anything from throwing an error, to interpreting in UTC or local time (but at least the date you meant) to an entirely different date or time.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to a Unix timestamp and that fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I already looked at that, it looks like that's for converting a timestamp to readable time. Either way my question was answered. Thanks for the help tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered. All I had to do was change the time string to a timestamp and that seemed to fix it.

```js
const countDownTime = new Date(1709290800000).getTime();
const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
const timeLeft = countDownTime - currentTime;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).