# react-admin Invalid Date in Safari

Tags: react-admin

Using react-admin with Safari causes "invalid date" with format yyyy-MM-dd, it seems because of: [Invalid date in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari)

Should there be support for this?

Comment: Hi, do you have a way to reproduce this issue? I recommend you to make it work on this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/olr88y53xy
And give me the link. Also, you can open an issue on the React Admin repo.

Comment: i don't think this is related to your browser(safari). Because if you have not provided correct date format then it'll give issue. But its correct like you mentioned yyyy-mm-dd.You should better check your code once again.