# customizable date picker script for forms

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, datepicker

I want to use  date picker on my form for selecting date.

I googled for it and found mostly import library scripts from live site. I don't want to use them.They are of limited use and I can't customize them.

Is there any good customizable date picker plugin which I can integrate and customize according my needs

I am working on zend-framework and heared about zendx. Is there any inbuilt date picker which I can call on my form element and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one of my projects based on Zend Framework, I used the UI jQuery Datepicker. You can find it here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Another usefull link is this: [Zend Framework - JQuery - Date Picker - Format Date to YYYY-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251673/zend-framework-jquery-date-picker-format-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: Thanks Aurelio. I will try. Can I change date format using it ?

Comment: @Dorman Sure, you can. In the first link you'll also find several examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zendx library for make datepicker element. Read this one.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.view.html